# How to append a record to a table via button on a form MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I've created a database revolving around a game, and I have a form for creating a character. There's a button on the form to create a character, provided data was entered in the characterName text box. However, I'm having an issue with adding the record to the Character table. It always replaces the first record or opens up a new blank table named Character with the same fields. I'm using the macro builder.

Comment: Can you post the macro that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a macro to add a new record to the table. Try this instead:

In the Navigation Pane on the left of your screen, click the Character table. Then go to the ribbon on top and under Create, click Form. This will make a form attached to your table. You can enter data into each field and it will all update to the table. Once you have made a few entries, you can use the navigation bar at the bottom of the form to browse between records, or create a new record.